# WPF ComboBox Selected Item to String

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

i´ve got a combobox and i m trying to set either the x:Name or the content of the selected comboItem (Both is okay, i´ll take the easier one) to an list. But i allways just geht things like this: 
System.Window.Controls.StackPanel or System.Window.Controls.Comboboxitem..

i tried to do it in many ways, so here s what i have right now:

```
                 sc.BC = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

and in Xaml the list looks like this:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedValuePath="Content" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="241,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" x:Name="wertwret">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Background="White" >---</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text=" item1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
```

can anybody help me ? thanks

Comment: What goes wrong?

Comment: when i m reading the sc.Bc, then it tells me the "strings" which starts with system.wi... and not something like "wertwret" or "--- item1" as i expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of `ComboBoxItem` is what you need, then just:

```
sc.BC = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Name;
```

"--- item1" is compound content of two UI elements.

Comment: Perfekt, thanks a lot. do you also know the way back ? so like this:

Comment: comboBox.SelectedItem = ls[i].BC;

Comment: so, i mean, it will be the selected item on the CB when i start the programm (cause i´ve got the ls list stored in a xml file)